# Text templates made in after effects render gibberish characters in Premiere Pro

Tags: premiere, after-effects

Upon importing the template composition, the layout get successfully imported, however the text is changed to random exotic characters. Why?

[image]

Comment: It's worth pointing out that it also looks like the kerning got screwed up somehow as well.

Answer (score 2):

Could be a text encoding problem. Is the original text using the Latin alphabet, or something more complex (accents, cedillas, or right to left languages)? If not, maybe try copying the text into a plaintext editor (like Notepad on a PC or TextEdit on the mac). Then copy it again, and paste back into AE? I haven't tried the premiere import yet, so these are guesses...